# clickhouse-client import file not found

Tags: linux, import, clickhouse, clickhouse-client

I'm trying to import the example data from the [link](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/getting-started/example-datasets/recipes/) but when I run the below command it can't find the csv file, Error: `-bash: full_dataset .csv: No such file or directory` and installed with clickhouse docker.

[image]

Where do I need to keep the "full_dataset.csv" file?

Comment: This error not from clickhouse-client, this error from bash
do you ensure you have full_dataset.csv in your home folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem by moving the "full_dataset.csv" file to the "root" directory.

Answer (score 1):

You need to either supply entire path or move the CSV file to clickhouse bin folder where the clickhouse-client resides.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

you need to download the csv dataset from the link and then only execute the code on the clickhouse documentation page, this is indicated https://recipenlg.cs.put.poznan.pl/dataset

Comment: [Posts on Stack Overflow have to be in English](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/13676). Please [edit] the post to translate it or remove the Russian text, in case the content is the same as the English.